# Xml updating with linq not working when quering

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have problem i'm trying to update a specific part of the XML with the linq query but it doesn't work. So i an xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DesignConfiguration>
  <Design name="CSF_Packages">
    <SourceFolder>C:\CSF_Packages</SourceFolder>
    <DestinationFolder>C:\Documents and Settings\xxx</DestinationFolder>
    <CopyLookups>True</CopyLookups>
    <CopyImages>False</CopyImages>
    <ImageSourceFolder>None</ImageSourceFolder>
    <ImageDesinationFolder>None</ImageDesinationFolder>
  </Design>
</DesignConfiguration>
```

I want to select the part where the part where there is `Design name="somethning"` and get the descendants and then update the descendants value that means this part:

```xml
    <SourceFolder>C:\CSF_Packages</SourceFolder>
    <DestinationFolder>C:\Documents and Settings\xxx</DestinationFolder>
    <CopyLookups>True</CopyLookups>
    <CopyImages>False</CopyImages>
    <ImageSourceFolder>None</ImageSourceFolder>
    <ImageDesinationFolder>None</ImageDesinationFolder>
```

I have this code:

```cs
        XDocument configXml = XDocument.Load(configXMLFileName);

        var updateData = configXml.Descendants("DesignConfiguration").Elements().Where(el => el.Name == "Design" &&
            el.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("CSF_Packages")).FirstOrDefault();

        configXml.Save(configXMLFileName);
```

I'm getting the null data in the `updateData` varibale. When I'm trying the Descendat's function through QuickWatch it also returns a null value. When I'm checking the configXML variable it has data that is my whole xml. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually have an element whose `name` attribute's value is "AFP_GRAFIKA"? In your sample only value for that attribute is "CSF_Packages"...

Comment: Yes because I was testing something and I gave you the code where I was trying something sorry for that.

Comment: It's OK, everything is fine with your sample, but I noticed that your code retrieves XML if you search for "CSF_Packages" instead of "AFP_GRAFIKA", so I thought that maybe the element that has attribute `name` with value "AFP_GRAFIKA" had a path different than `DesignConfiguration\Design`.

Comment: I did searched for this but it still din't work. Problem was that descendants function was returning null no matter what I asked for. So there was nothing to retrieve when this was null I guess. I will update the post so that will be no confusions to that matter :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var updateData = 
    confixXml
    .Root                     //Root Element
    .Elements("Design")       //All elements under root called Design
    .Where(element => (String)element.Attribute("name") == "AFP_GRAFIKA") //Find the one with the name Attribute of AFP_GRAFIKA
    .FirstOrDefault();        //Grab the first one it finds or return null.

if (updateData != null)
{
    var myElements = 
        updateData
        .Elements();          //All the elements under the Design node
}
```

Comment: this is working !!! :) thank you very much. One last thing could you explain why my soultion didn't work and other ones that I found on StacOverFlow? Because there were simmilar examples to mine but they didn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm wondering no, how to update the elements inside, by foreach loop? And then save it to xml ?

Comment: Yes, that's the best way to approach it,

Comment: But in the collection I have tree elements how to change it one by one? This function which has the ubove solution has a parameter which is an object. This has properties like SourceFolder and the rest so, i would like to change that based on this data. But if I understand it right I can only change one item in the collection and assing data from the object property to this item. Hope that's understandable :)

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("");

XElement settings = (from children in xml.Descendants("DesignConfiguration")
                        where children.Name.Equals("Design") && children.Attribute("name").Equals("CSF_Packages")
                        select children).FirstOrDefault();

settings.Element("SourceFolder").SetValue("filepath");
settings.Element("CopyImages").SetValue(true);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the Descendant's function didn't work, it retrieved null (I've described this above) and it didn't want to select my value. Thank you or your help, DaveShaw's answer did work though but I don't know why this didn't work and DaveShaw's did. As I've posted I'm new to this and maybe my building of xml is wrong.

Comment: I've checked this on my example - settings has null value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've managed to fix the problem. I don't know why but it worked. It seems that the Descendants function returns null as a stand alone function but with linq it works. So for my solution only thing what should be done is this:

```
 var updateData = (from s in configXml.Descendants("Design") 
                   where s.Attribute("name").Value == design.DesignName 
                  select s).First();
```

At first before I sent you my question I've tried this but I didn't have the select s part. Besides when I wrote the where s.Atribute part in the curly brackets I've inserted the design.DesignName object instead of the name of the attribute. So no it works ok. Thanks for your help and everything. Til nex time. Have a nice day/night everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Because DesignConfiguration was your root node, the Descendants("DesignConfiguration) was returning null. By using the .Descendants("Design"), you were looking at child nodes, not the self.