# How to update a collection of xml Elements?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm a liitle bit green to the saving reeding xml and linq in c#. This is my code:

```cs
    public static void EditConfiguration (DesignConfiguration design)
    {
        XDocument configXml = XDocument.Load(configXMLFileName);
        var updateData = configXml.Root.Elements("Design").Where(element => (String)element.Attribute("name") == design.DesignName).FirstOrDefault();

        if (updateData != null)
        {
            var myElements = updateData.Elements();  //All the elements under th Design node 
            configXml.Save(configXMLFileName);    
       }            
    }
```

In the myElements variable there are such elements:

```xml
<SourceFolder>C:\CSF_Packages</SourceFolder>
<DestinationFolder>C:\Inetpub</DestinationFolder>
<CopyLookups>True</CopyLookups>
<CopyImages>False</CopyImages>
<ImageSourceFolder>None</ImageSourceFolder>
<ImageDesinationFolder>None</ImageDesinationFolder>
```

I want to update each of this elements with the value from the design configuration object. This wouldn't be so hard if i had one value in the object but there are values like so:

design.SourceFolder
design.DesitnationFolder

etc (just like the elements). The object provides new values for above elements. It's obvious to me that I should use the foreach loop but the result when I'm using it is not the one I want...

This is my foreach loop:

```cs
            foreach (var item in myElements )
            {
                item.SetElementValue("SourceFolder", design.SourceFolder);
            }
```

In the loop there is only one element for the presentation needs, but I wanted to put more of them in the loop. And this is what I get:

```xml
<SourceFolder>C:\CSF_Packages<SourceFolder>C:\CSF_Packages</SourceFolder></SourceFolder>
<DestinationFolder>None<SourceFolder>C:\CSF_Packages</SourceFolder></DestinationFolder>
<CopyLookups>True<SourceFolder>C:\CSF_Packages</SourceFolder></CopyLookups>
<CopyImages>False<SourceFolder>C:\CSF_Packages</SourceFolder></CopyImages>
<ImageSourceFolder>C:\Inetpub<SourceFolder>C:\CSF_Packages</SourceFolder></ImageSourceFolder>
<ImageDesinationFolder>None<SourceFolder>C:\CSF_Packages</SourceFolder></ImageDesinationFolder>
```

I would like to have:

```
<SourceFolder>new_value_from the DesignConfiguration object from the SourceFolder property</SourceFolder>
<DestinationFolder>new_value_from the DesignConfiguration object from the Desitnation Folder property</DestinationFolder>
<CopyLookups>new_value_from the DesignConfiguration object from the CopyLookups property</CopyLookups>
```

and so on...
please help a noobie in the stress :) Thank you very much.

Comment: What result do you get with the foreach loop and what result are you expecting?

Comment: I've updated my post for the information what I want to do :) Soryy for that....

Comment: The nesting of that last XML is totally wrong. Please fix it.

Comment: What is the type of design.SourceFolder?

Comment: String, the propperties of the design object are mostly strings besidse CopyLookups and CopyImages those are type bool.

Comment: Ok I've managed to solve my problem, should I send it here? It was very simple :)

Comment: here is the link to the soultion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816102/xml-updating-with-linq-not-working-when-quering  and also here you can see from what point the problem started, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the childs XElements and then add the new ones to the parent.
Try these (not tested):

```
public static void EditConfiguration (DesignConfiguration design)
{
    XDocument configXml = XDocument.Load(configXMLFileName);
    var updateData = configXml.Root.Elements("Design").Where(element => (String)element.Attribute("name") == design.DesignName).FirstOrDefault();

    if (updateData != null)
    {
        var myElements = updateData.Elements();  //All the elements under th Design node 
        myElements.Remove();
        updateData.SetElementValue("SourceFolder", design.SourceFolder);
        updateData.SetElementValue("DestinationFolder", design.DestinationFolder);
        updateData.SetElementValue("CopyLookups", design.CopyLookups);

        configXml.Save(configXMLFileName);
   }            
}
```